# Perfectly scroll to top. but when i scroll down and click anywhere on page, again scroll moves to the top

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

Here is my code.
Works fine when renders the page but changes to top when i click down somwhere

```
   ngAfterViewChecked() {
      // this.mainPageComponent.rightPanel.nativeElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
      this.element.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
   }
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior of [`ngAfterViewChecked`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)

Answer (score 0):

ngAfterViewChecked is triggered every time after angular has check the view of your component.

You should use ngOnInit if you want this effect to be trigger only at initialisation.

cf : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I tries several life cycle hooks, same problem exists

Comment: ngOnInit hook is only trigger once by component. I hardly doubt that you will have the same behavior. Could you try with ngOnInit and check execution with a breakpoint ( or console.log ) ?